# BoxFit.cover in ClipRRect in Hero in Container Stack doesn't fill container

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to center the image in the Container. I tried to adjust the fit property but it doesn't seem to work. What can I try next?

```
 Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
                      blurRadius: 6.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Hero(
                  tag: widget.destination.imageUrl,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    child: Image(
                      image: NetworkImage(widget.destination.imageUrl),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width to double.infinity in Image Widget

```
child: Hero(
                  tag: widget.destination.imageUrl,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    child: const Image(
                      width: double.infinity, //TODO: Set width to double.infinity
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          widget.destination.imageUrl),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: It doesn’t work but thx for trying

Comment: Can you share entire code for better understanding